# Как работает вложенный цикл for и while?

Tags: java, while, for

Не могу разобраться и понять работу вложенных циклов как они работают и какой из начинает работать первым?

1. Что делает первый цикл?
2. Что делает внутренний то есть вложенный цикл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Ваш пример с двумя циклами можно переписать следующим образом

```
void firstFor() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        secondFor(i);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

void secondFor(int i) {
    for (int j = i; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
```

Отсюда видно, что первый `for` передает методу (второму циклу) значение переменной `i` ждет его выполнения и выводит в консоль символ перевода строки, после чего еще раз переходит на новую строку и переходит к следующей итерации,

а второй цикл, основываясь на значении полученной `i` выполняет какое-то количество последовательных печатей символа `*` по штуки на строчку.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
     }
System.out.println();
i++;
}
```

Двумерный массив так сказать. Первым начинает работать цикл while, так как в него пришло значение переменной i = 0; Дальше начинает работу цикл for, и перебирает все свои значение. После этого работа цикла for завершается, переменная "i" цикла while увеличивается на 1, происходит проверка условия и дальше вступает в работу цикл while и т.д.

Вот пример с двух циклов for.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы уточнили какой цикл вложен, 2 for, 2 while или while + for (как чаще всего бывает).
В идеале нужен пример кода.
В любом случае for и While оба содержат условия при котором выполняется тело цикла, либо в крайнем случае Break в теле цикла, для его прерывания. 
Тело цикла заключается в фигурные скобки {} и выполняется пока условие истино.